# Examples and counter-examples for rings

Tags: ring-theory, examples-counterexamples

Here's what I am trying to do:

[image]

1. Listing mnemonics used:

   - $D_n(\Bbb R)$ to denote diagonal $n \times n$ matrices with real coefficients.
   - I.D. - Integral domain, E.D. Euclidean Domain
2. Much of the data was collected from Wikipedia and SE.
3. Using [this template](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template:Commutative_ring_classes) from Wikipedia,

$$\text{Commutative rings}\supset\text{I.D.}\supset\text{U.F.D.}\supset\text{P.I.D.}\supset\text{E.D.}\supset\text{Fields}\supset\text{Finite Fields}$$

each column is a subset of previous column, in other words, examples for UFD works for Integral Domain (ID) and commutative rings, and so on (excluding non-commutative rings).

4. "Examples" given in bold are counter examples to the category to its right. That is, $\Bbb Z\times \Bbb Z$ is a Commutative Ring, but not an Integral Domain.

***My doubts are***:

1. Can someone verify if the data I gathered is correct and it will be great if someone can provide more simple examples in each category!
2. Is this [template in Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template:Commutative_ring_classes) correct? Else, are there any counter examples?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. I didn't spot any mistakes so far. As for more examples, you may find some at the [DaRT](http://ringtheory.herokuapp.com).
2. Yes, the template is fine.

Comment: Thank you for DaRT! Just what I was looking for!